# python code output is once but put into function and output duplicates itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that works fine and the output is correct.

```
game_type = input("ongoing competition or single play?  ")

if game_type == 'single play':
    users = (input("how many players? "))
    while not users.isdigit():
        users = (input("how many players? "))
    users = int(users)

    players = {}

    for person in range(users):
        name = input("player's name?  ")
        players[name] = []

----output----
ongoing competition or single play?  single play
how many players? 2
player's name?  bob
player's name?  red
```

But when I try to put the code into functions it asks me "how many players" twice in the output.  I'm not sure why it's doing this.

```
def people():
    users = (input("how many players? "))
    while not users.isdigit():
        users = (input("how many players? "))
    return int(users)

users = people()
players = {}

def player_name():
    for person in range(users):
        name = input("player's name?  ")
        players[name] = []
---------------------------------------------------------
game_type = input("ongoing competition or single play?  ")

from func import *

if game_type == 'single play':
    people()
    player_name()

----output----
ongoing competition or single play?  single play
how many players? 2
how many players? 2
player's name?  red
player's name?  bob
```

Comment: You need to remove the `users = people() ` because you are calling people() twice so it is asking you twice. You are calling it above and then again when asking if it is a single player game.

Comment: @FivePlyPaper I removed `users = people()`  and now I get an error that says 'users' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You call people() twice. You assign the return value of it in the global scope to the variable "users" and then call it in an if statement. If you need the same variables in different scopes then you may want to create a class and do some configuration in your constructor.

Comment: so if a function is assigned to a variable, then it will be executable code and not static?  How would I re-write this so that `player_name()` takes in the number from `people()`

Comment: @belmer01 I edited my answer to clarify. But to answer you question, if you have a function named foo you can say bar = foo then call bar(). But still the problem is that your function is being executed twice.